# ValueError: in user code: - Cryptic error message when training model in R (calling model.fit)

Tags: r, tensorflow, keras

The following is my code. I'm trying to train a model with 110 neurons in the input layer.

```
library(tensorflow)
library(keras)

datafile <- read.csv("/file/path") # my file has 111 columns, 4364 rows, all entries are strings/characters. I'm unable to provide the actual file or its contents. There are two classes under "target"

dt = sort(sample(nrow(datafile), nrow(datafile)*.7))

train <- datafile[dt,]
test <- datafile[-dt,]

X_train <- train[, -1]
y_train <- train[, 1]

X_test <- test[, -1]
y_test <- test[, 1]

y_train <- to_categorical(y_train, 2)
y_test <- to_categorical(y_test, 2)

# Build the model
model <- keras_model_sequential() 
model %>% 
  layer_dense(units = 64, activation = 'relu', input_shape = c(110)) %>% 
  layer_dropout(rate = 0.4) %>% 
  layer_dense(units = 32, activation = 'relu') %>%
  layer_dropout(rate = 0.3) %>%
  layer_dense(units = 2, activation = 'softmax')

summary(model)

model %>% compile(
  loss = 'categorical_crossentropy',
  optimizer = optimizer_rmsprop(),
  metrics = c('accuracy')
)

history <- model %>% fit(
  X_train, y_train, 
  epochs = 30, batch_size = 128, 
  validation_split = 0.2,
  verbose = 2
)
```

The following is the error message. It's not very informative, but perhaps someone is able to understand what is going on. I think the most informative bit might be `ValueError: Layer sequential_3 expects 1 input(s), but it received 110 input tensors.`

```
 Error in py_call_impl(callable, dots$args, dots$keywords) : 
  ValueError: in user code:

    /Users/anupa/Library/r-miniconda/envs/r-reticulate/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:805 train_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    /Users/anupa/Library/r-miniconda/envs/r-reticulate/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:795 step_function  **
        outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    /Users/anupa/Library/r-miniconda/envs/r-reticulate/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:1259 run
        return self._extended.call_for_each_replica(fn, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
    /Users/anupa/Library/r-miniconda/envs/r-reticulate/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:2730 call_for_each_replica
        return self._call_for_each_replica(fn, args, kwargs)
    /Users/anupa/Library/r-miniconda/envs/r-reticulate/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute 
27.
stop(structure(list(message = "ValueError: in user code:\n\n    /Users/anupa/Library/r-miniconda/envs/r-reticulate/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:805 train_function  *\n        return step_function(self, iterator)\n    /Users/anupa/Library/r-miniconda/envs/r-reticulate/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:795 step_function  **\n        outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))\n    /Users/anupa/Library/r-miniconda/envs/r-reticulate/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:1259 run\n        return self._extended.call_for_each_replica(fn, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)\n    /Users/anupa/Library/r-miniconda/envs/r-reticulate/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:2730 call_for_each_replica\n        return self._call_for_each_replica(fn, args, kwargs)\n    /Users/anupa/Library/r-miniconda/envs/r-reticulate/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:3417 _call_for_each_replica\n        return fn(*args, **kwargs)\n    /Users/anupa/Library/r-miniconda/envs/r-reticulate/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:788 run_step  **\n        outputs = model.train_step(data)\n    /Users/anupa/Library/r-miniconda/envs/r-reticulate/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:754 train_step\n        y_pred = self(x, training=True)\n    /Users/anupa/Library/r-miniconda/envs/r-reticulate/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py:998 __call__\n        input_spec.assert_input_compatibility(self.input_spec, inputs, self.name)\n    /Users/anupa/Library/r-miniconda/envs/r-reticulate/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/input_spec.py:207 assert_input_compatibility\n        ' input tensors. Inputs received: ' + str(inputs))\n\n    ValueError: Layer sequential_3 expects 1 input(s), but it received 110 input tensors. Inputs received: [<tf.Tensor 'ExpandDims:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=string>, <tf.Tensor 'ExpandDims_1:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=string>, <tf.Tensor 'ExpandDims_2:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=string>, <tf.Tensor 'ExpandDims_3:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=string>, <tf.Tensor 'ExpandDims_4:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=string>, <tf.Tensor 'ExpandDims_5:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=string>, <tf.Tensor 'ExpandDims_6:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=string>, <tf.Tensor 'ExpandDims_7:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=string>, <tf.Tensor 'ExpandDims_8:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=string>, <tf.Tensor 'ExpandDims_9:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=string>, <tf.Tensor 'ExpandDims_10:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=string>, <tf.Tensor 'ExpandDims_11:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=string>, <tf.Tensor 'ExpandDims_12:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=string>, <tf.Tensor 'ExpandDims_13:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=string>, <tf.Tensor 'ExpandDims_14:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=string>, <tf.Tensor 'ExpandDims_15:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=string>, <tf.Tensor 'ExpandDims_16:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=string>, <tf.Tensor 'ExpandDims_17:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=string>, <tf.Tensor 'ExpandDims_18:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=string>, <tf.Tensor 'ExpandDims_19:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=string>, <tf.Tensor 'ExpandDims_20:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=string>, <tf.Tensor 'ExpandDims_21:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=string>, <tf.Tensor 'ExpandDims_22:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=string>, <tf.Tensor 'ExpandDims_23:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=string>, <tf.Tensor 'ExpandDims_24:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=string>, <tf.Tensor 'ExpandDims_25:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=string>, <tf.Tensor 'ExpandDims_26:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=string>, <tf.Tensor 'ExpandDims_27:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=string>, <tf.Tensor 'ExpandDims_28:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=string>, <tf.Tensor 'ExpandDims_29:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=string>, <tf.Tensor 'ExpandDims_30:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=string>, <tf.Tensor 'ExpandDims_31:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=string>, <tf.Tensor 'ExpandDims_32:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=string>, <tf.Tensor 'ExpandDims_33:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=string>, <tf.Tensor 'ExpandDims_34:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=string>, <tf.Tensor 'ExpandDims_35:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=string>, <tf.Tensor 'ExpandDims_36:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=string>, <tf.Tensor 'ExpandDims_37:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=string>, <tf.Tensor 'ExpandDims_38:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=string>, <tf.Tensor 'ExpandDims_39:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=string>, <tf.Tensor 'ExpandDims_40:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=string>, <tf.Tensor 'ExpandDims_41:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=string>, <tf.Tensor 'ExpandDims_42:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=string>, <tf.Tensor 'ExpandDims_43:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=string>, <tf.Tensor 'ExpandDims_44:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=string>, <tf.Tensor 'ExpandDims_45:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=string>, <tf.Tensor 'ExpandDims_46:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=string>, <tf.Tensor 'ExpandDims_47:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=string>, <tf.Tensor 'ExpandDims_48:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=string>, <tf.Tensor 'ExpandDims_49:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=string>, <tf.Tensor 'ExpandDims_50:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=string>, <tf.Tensor 'ExpandDims_51:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=string>, <tf.Tensor 'ExpandDims_52:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=string>, <tf.Tensor 'ExpandDims_53:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=string>, <tf.Tensor 'ExpandDims_54:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=string>, <tf.Tensor 'ExpandDims_55:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=string>, <tf.Tensor 'ExpandDims_56:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=string>, <tf.Tensor 'ExpandDims_57:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=string>, <tf.Tensor 'ExpandDims_58:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=string>, <tf.Tensor 'ExpandDims_59:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=string>, <tf.Tensor 'ExpandDims_60:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=string>, <tf.Tensor 'ExpandDims_61:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=string>, <tf.Tensor 'ExpandDims_62:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=string>, <tf.Tensor 'ExpandDims_63:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=string>, <tf.Tensor 'ExpandDims_64:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=string>, <tf.Tensor 'ExpandDims_65:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=string>, <tf.Tensor 'ExpandDims_66:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=string>, <tf.Tensor 'ExpandDims_67:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=string>, <tf.Tensor 'ExpandDims_68:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=string>, <tf.Tensor 'ExpandDims_69:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=string>, <tf.Tensor 'ExpandDims_70:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=string>, <tf.Tensor 'ExpandDims_71:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=string>, <tf.Tensor 'ExpandDims_72:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=string>, <tf.Tensor 'ExpandDims_73:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=string>, <tf.Tensor 'ExpandDims_74:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=string>, <tf.Tensor 'ExpandDims_75:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=string>, <tf.Tensor 'ExpandDims_76:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=string>, <tf.Tensor 'ExpandDims_77:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=string>, <tf.Tensor 'ExpandDims_78:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=string>, <tf.Tensor 'ExpandDims_79:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=string>, <tf.Tensor 'ExpandDims_80:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=string>, <tf.Tensor 'ExpandDims_81:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=string>, <tf.Tensor 'ExpandDims_82:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=string>, <tf.Tensor 'ExpandDims_83:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=string>, <tf.Tensor 'ExpandDims_84:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=string>, <tf.Tensor 'ExpandDims_85:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=string>, <tf.Tensor 'ExpandDims_86:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=string>, <tf.Tensor 'ExpandDims_87:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=string>, <tf.Tensor 'ExpandDims_88:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=string>, <tf.Tensor 'ExpandDims_89:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=string>, <tf.Tensor 'ExpandDims_90:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=string>, <tf.Tensor 'ExpandDims_91:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=string>, <tf.Tensor 'ExpandDims_92:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=string>, <tf.Tensor 'ExpandDims_93:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=string>, <tf.Tensor 'ExpandDims_94:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=string>, <tf.Tensor 'ExpandDims_95:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=string>, <tf.Tensor 'ExpandDims_96:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=string>, <tf.Tensor 'ExpandDims_97:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=string>, <tf.Tensor 'ExpandDims_98:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=string>, <tf.Tensor 'ExpandDims_99:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=string>, <tf.Tensor 'ExpandDims_100:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=string>, <tf.Tensor 'ExpandDims_101:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=string>, <tf.Tensor 'ExpandDims_102:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=string>, <tf.Tensor 'ExpandDims_103:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=string>, <tf.Tensor 'ExpandDims_104:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=string>, <tf.Tensor 'ExpandDims_105:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=string>, <tf.Tensor 'ExpandDims_106:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=string>, <tf.Tensor 'ExpandDims_107:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=string>, <tf.Tensor 'ExpandDims_108:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=string>, <tf.Tensor 'ExpandDims_109:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=string>]\n", 
    call = py_call_impl(callable, dots$args, dots$keywords), 
    cppstack = structure(list(file = "", line = -1L, stack = c("1   reticulate.so                       0x000000010ea5f05e _ZN4Rcpp9exceptionC2EPKcb + 222", 
    "2   reticulate.so                       0x000000010ea676a5 _ZN4Rcpp4stopERKNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS0_11char_traitsIcEENS0_9allocatorIcEEEE + 53",  ... 
26.
wrapper at func_graph.py#977
25.
wrapped_fn at def_function.py#634
24.
func_graph_from_py_func at func_graph.py#990
23.
_create_graph_function at function.py#3206
22.
_maybe_define_function at function.py#3361
21.
_get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected at function.py#2969
20.
_initialize at def_function.py#726
19.
_call at def_function.py#871
18.
__call__ at def_function.py#828
17.
fit at training.py#1100
16.
(structure(function (...) 
{
    dots <- py_resolve_dots(list(...))
    result <- py_call_impl(callable, dots$args, dots$keywords) ... 
15.
do.call(object$fit, args) 
14.
fit.keras.engine.training.Model(., X_train, y_train, epochs = 30, 
    batch_size = 128, validation_split = 0.2, verbose = 2) 
13.
fit(., X_train, y_train, epochs = 30, batch_size = 128, validation_split = 0.2, 
    verbose = 2) 
12.
function_list[[k]](value) 
11.
withVisible(function_list[[k]](value)) 
10.
freduce(value, `_function_list`) 
9.
`_fseq`(`_lhs`) 
8.
eval(quote(`_fseq`(`_lhs`)), env, env) 
7.
eval(quote(`_fseq`(`_lhs`)), env, env) 
6.
withVisible(eval(quote(`_fseq`(`_lhs`)), env, env)) 
5.
model %>% fit(X_train, y_train, epochs = 30, batch_size = 128, 
    validation_split = 0.2, verbose = 2) at nn_albase.R#37
4.
eval(ei, envir) 
3.
eval(ei, envir) 
2.
withVisible(eval(ei, envir))
```

My guess is that there's something wrong with the format of X_train and/or y_train, any suggestions for how to fix this would be much appreciated.
Thank you!

Comment: You did not include the error message, people cannot help you without it.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy thank you, i've edited it. i forgot to include the error message.

Comment: The error message is incomplete, you need to include the whole python traceback.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy yes i know. i'm somehow unable to show the traceback. :( I'm using RStudio, initially i was able to display the traceback but now it truncates the message and RStudio is not giving me the option to view more

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy got it. the important part of the error message i think might be "ValueError: Layer sequential_3 expects 1 input(s), but it received 110 input tensors."

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy made another edit

Comment: Try to change `categorical_crossentropy` to `binary_crossentropy` because your `units =2`, `optimizer='rmsprop'` and maybe `activation = 'softmax'`. It is very hard to given a nice tip without any data in `datafile`.

Comment: @Leprechault the data has 111 columns and 4364 rows. the items are all characters/strings. i tried changing according to what you mentioned and am still getting the same error :/